# Difference between true standard deviation and population standard deviation

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

What exactly is the difference between the two? Is it true that if you have been given the true standard deviation, you have to use the Z-score and if you have been given sample standard deviation, you have to use the t-score?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have $n\ge2$ independent samples $X_1,\,\cdots,\,X_n$ of a mean-$\mu$, SD-$\sigma$ distribution, $\bar{X}:=\frac1n\sum_iX_i$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mu$, and $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ (whose square root we denote $s$), and so is $\frac1n\sum_i(X_i-\mu)^2$ (but you can't use it without knowing $\mu$ exactly). If the sampled distribution is normal, $Z:=\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma}$ is too, but $T:=\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{s}$ is $t$-distributed.

Comment: My guess is that, after a decade of operation, somewhere on this site, there is an explanation as to the reason why $n-1$ is needed in one formula instead $n$. Did you search? This is a prime reason for my EoQS flags, not that I have used many lately.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The question is about a bit more than just that. I thought it would be helpful if I disentangle multiple questions within it, which should cover what the OP needs even if their exact point of confusion is ambiguous. Do you think I should convert what I've written into a comment?

Comment: I don't know what is best for I don't frequent these tags. The question appeared in the review queue. It seems to me to be pretty standard. FWIW I refrained from voting, as I don't know how well past material covers this theme.